# Infer rules that have missing facts

Tags: algorithm, math, machine-learning, rule-engine, inference

Suppose I have a medical rule: A man is healthy, he has insomnia syndrome, he is advised to take sleeping pills and meet a doctor. This rule has a certainty factor 0.9 (degree of subjective belief that a particular rule is true, range [0; 1]).

```
Status(Fatigue) ^ Syndrone(Insomnia)
-> Treatment(TakeSleepingPills) ^ Treatment(MeetDoctor) {CF = 0.9}
```

If I has a known fact `Status(Fatigue)`, how can I infer `Treatment(TakeSleepingPills)` and `Treatment(MeetDoctor)` without a missing fact `Syndrone(Insomnia)`?

There are many machine learning approaches, such as [Probabilistic Mention Model](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~sorowerm/Publications/ijcai11_explicit_mention_model.pdf), [Sampling distribution inference, Bayesian inference](http://qwone.com/~jason/trg/papers/rubin-missing-76.pdf),... But are there other ways without using machine learning?

Comment: "If I have a known fact Status(Fatigue)" - are you always given exactly one symptom or can you be given any number? If any number, should we ignore the possibility of being given different symptoms which don't all fall into the same rule? It's not uncommon for doctors to need to disregard unrelated symptoms to get to a diagnosis and treatment plan, but I'm guessing you're just trying to solve this in theory.

Comment: @Dukeling I'm trying to solve this problem, too. A rule can have both crisp facts and fuzzy facts. If I had a crisp fact `Health=0.6`, I could fuzzify it into 2 fuzzy fact `Health(Fatigue)` and `Health(Healthy)`. I still don't know how to infer this rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use **answer set programming** to derive rules and outcomes. Basically, you have to represent your problem in a form of logical equations and run a special program to solve given problem even in case of missing information. However, in my opinion it **will not** be simpler than machine learning.

You can read the following:

1. [What is Answer Set Programming](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/vl/papers/wiasp.pdf)
2. [Answer Set Programming via Examples](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~cannata/cs345/Class%20Notes/32%20Yuliya%20Spring%202011%20cs345Presentation.pdf)

Solvers:

1. [Potassco](http://potassco.sourceforge.net/)
2. [SModels](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/smodels/)

Comment: why did you think answer set programming was harder than machine learning?

Comment: It's not harder to my taste. But it's not simpler  and requires some preliminary studies.